# shadow under custom uiview

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-graphics

I'm trying to add a shadow under my custom view, I have the following code:

```
CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextSetShadow(context, CGSizeMake(0, 2), 3.0);
CGRect shadowRect = CGRectMake(self.bounds.origin.x,
                               self.bounds.origin.y + self.bounds.size.height,
                               self.bounds.size.width,
                               3.0);
CGContextFillRect(context, shadowRect);
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

But the shadow isn't visible.

Comment: **Hope the link will cheer you.** [Click here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_shadows/dq_shadows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH208-TPXREF101)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    UIColor *color = [UIColor grayColor];
    CGColorRef gray = color.CGColor;
    self.layer.shadowColor = gray;
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
    self.layer.shadowRadius = 2;
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1;
    self.layer.borderColor = red;
    self.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.bounds].CGPath;
    self.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
```